# What should we do with "名 mixed up with 各" questions?

Tags: discussion

How do we deal with this sort of question?

1. [meaning of 名種設定?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/meaning-of-%E5%90%8D%E7%A8%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)
2. [Is there a difference between 名国 and 国?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11247/is-there-a-difference-between-%E5%90%8D%E5%9B%BD-and-%E5%9B%BD)

The former was closed as too localized, implying the question would never come up again, but the latter was closed as a duplicate!  Since this contradicts "too localized", @cypher voted to reopen, but as of this writing it is stuck at 2 reopen votes.

What should we do?

EDIT: Just to put a cap on this, we'll look at the results from this after 7 days.

<sub>(and the question has been 'feature'd)</sub>

Comment: Nitpicking: They changed the name “exact duplicate” to “duplicate” recently.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thanks, updated!  I don't know what the implication of "duplicate" versus "exact duplicate" is, though.

Comment: I prefer just “duplicate” because the reason “exact duplicate” was used for not-so-exact duplicates anyway.  But just in case, I do not think that this difference matters to what we should do with mixed-up-kanji questions.  (As I wrote, it was just a nitpicking. :) )

Comment: I don't understand how people are getting `各` mixed up with `名` anyway?  Is it a certain font that makes it look similar?  Font size?

Comment: @istrasci: I had never thought that these two letters might look similar before seeing these questions, but thinking about it, we could argue that the difference between the two letters is just the length of the third stroke.

Comment: As the one who started the first question I can tell you how I got it mixed up (as far as I recall). I didn't find it online but on a paper with good fonts. When I wanted to search the dictionary for this word I had to build it up kanji by kanji, and I accidentally got 名 instead of 各. When I didn't find a dictionary meaning or any google results I DID check to see if I have to correct kanji, but finding mistakes is a lot harder then just reading or writing when you don't know the language. It's practically a game of "find the differences" which I gave up on and posted the question here.

Comment: I still think you guys are too quick on the closing finger though...

Answer (score 7):

Since [meaning of 名種設定?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/meaning-of-%E5%90%8D%E7%A8%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A) isn't getting enough reopen votes, perhaps it really *is* Too Localized.  After all, no one's likely to ask about the exact same compound, even if they do contain the same mistake.

Let's create a more general question about mixed-up kanji like 各　→　名.  Then, when questions come up, we can mark them as duplicates of our more general question.  The answer should describe the problem generally, but it should also have specific examples of easily mixed-up kanji.

We should also make the answer community wiki so we can add new examples as they come up.

Comment: If this happens, then we'll also want a mod to reclose the "too localized" question as a duplicate of the new "canonical" one.

Answer (score 3):

We don't need to do anything.  It's fine the way it is, with question 1 closed as too localized, and question 2 closed as a duplicate of question 1.

Answer (score -2):

We don't need to make a new question.  We just need to reopen question 1 and mark others as duplicates.